# use result of concat ids in where in condition

Tags: mysql, concatenation

I have a query like this:

```
SET @myId := null;
update temp_tbl set status = 1, id = (SELECT @myId := id)
where status = 0 limit 1;
```

Now I want to change it like this:

```
SET @myIds := null;
update temp_tbl set status = 1, id = (SELECT @myIds := CONCAT_WS(',', id, @myIds ) )
where status = 0;

select @myIds;
```

It returns:

```
1,45,46,49,50,54,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76
```

I need to have a select like this:

```
select * from temp_tbl where id in (@myIds);
```

but it returns only the first one!

- because of bad performance I don't want to use from  `FIND_IN_SET`

Comment: `FIND_IN_SET()`

Comment: @Akina Find in set doesn't use any index and it scans all table. If we use temporary table better than find in set!

Comment: *Find in set doesn't use any index* Of course - you search string literal in string literal. But alternative - parsing CSV to rowset - is more expensive. I think that you must post the task, not the way which you decide to use for to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [prepared statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/execute.html):

```
  SET @myIds = "3,2,1";
  SET @queryString = CONCAT("SELECT * FROM Test where id in (",@myIds,")");
  SELECT @queryString;
  PREPARE stmt FROM @queryString;
  EXECUTE stmt;
```

For your example in my `phpadmin` I ran it in a stored procedure like this:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_test
BEGIN
  SET @myIds = "1,45,46,49,50,54,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76";
  SET @queryString = CONCAT("SELECT * FROM temp_tbl where id in (",@myIds,")");
  SELECT @queryString;
  PREPARE stmt FROM @queryString;
  EXECUTE stmt;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```